# Routing error in ruby rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

So, I am trying to send a GET request from Postman and trying to run the method called question. I am also passing parameters in my request. 
I keep getting a routing error. Im not sure why. 
The way I am trying to route it is given below

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

namespace 'api' do
 namespace 'v1' do

  get 'questions', to: 'application#/api/v1/question'
  end
 end
end
```

My questions_controller.rb has a method called question. The file is in app/controllers/api/v1/questions_controller.rb

The error I am getting,
[Picture of the error I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2vJP.png)

Comment: The error says `uninitialized constant Api::V1::ApplicationController`. Do you have a `Api::V1::ApplicationController`? How does your `QuestionController` look like? What class does it inherit from?

Comment: added QuestionController

Comment: `get 'questions', to: 'questions#/api/v1/question'` try this

Comment: Gabbar, just tried what you said. The error I got was, "exception": "#<AbstractController::ActionNotFound: The action '/api/v1/question' could not be found for Api::V1::QuestionsController>",

Comment: `get 'questions', to: 'questions#question'`  you already namespaced the pato to questions controller, in namespace you should provide just questions controller

Comment: Oh, think that worked Dima. Thanks. But now I get, "exception": "#<ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0..1)>",.. Not sure why I'm getting the wrong number of arguments?

Comment: It's likely about invoking `check_arguments` or `create_question` with two arguments. Check the signatures of these methods

Comment: you send bad request from postman. you have `questions?lower=5;upper=10` but right is `questions?lower=5&upper=10`

Comment: Oh my god! Thanks everyone. I got it finally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried this?

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

namespace 'api' do
 namespace 'v1' do

  get 'questions', to: 'questions#question'
  end
 end
end
```

Since you already said your namespaces maybe it isn't necessary